# How to create a scalable function to subset a dataframe into a list of dataframes using combination of values of two variables

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

I would appreciate any help to subset my `sampleDT` below into a list of data frames such that each of the data frames in this list is defined by each unique combination of the variables `imput` and `draw`.

The approach `data_variable <- split(data, data$variable)` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230760/create-a-list-of-dataframes-that-are-generated-by-applying-a-function-to-subsets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671427/subset-dataframe-into-a-list) only works when the intention is to use only one variable as the rule. In my analyses I might have more than two variables to use as the rule for the subsetting, therefore a solution that can easily be adapted to more than two variables would be much appreciated.

**#sample data**

```
sampleDT<-structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), imput = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), B = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Pass = c(278, 
278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 
153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79), Fail = c(740, 
743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 
1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 
743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 
1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 
7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 
1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 
7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 
1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 
7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 
740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 
1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 
742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 
1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 
740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 
1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 
7581, 7581, 7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 
1731, 1731, 1731, 740, 743, 742, 743, 740, 7581, 7581, 7581, 
7581, 7581, 1231, 1232, 1235, 1235, 1232, 1731, 1732, 1731, 1731, 
1731), draw = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Weights_1", "Weights_2", "Weights_3", 
"Weights_4", "Weights_5", "Weights_6", "Weights_7", "Weights_8", 
"Weights_9", "Weights_10"), class = "factor"), weight = c(4, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 12, 12, 13, 12, 12, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 15, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 
10, 12, 12, 12, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `split(sampleDT, list(sampleDT$imput, sampleDT$draw))`?

Comment: Alternative notation: `split(sampleDT, sampleDT[, c("imput", "draw")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
split(sampleDT,interaction(sampleDT$imput,sampleDT$draw))
```

that's a list, and easily updated to include more variables